# Need to specify the age interval in subset

Tags: r

I need to specify interval of age in subset function. Can I ask how to write it?

```
W = subset(CAR, subset == Age=[16,17], 
                 select=c("Name","END","MEZ","EKT","X","Y"))
```

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a ```dput()``` of your data or some reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

```
W = subset(CAR, Age%in%c(16,17), select=c("Name","END","MEZ","EKT","X","Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

And in case Age is continuous instead of discrete:

```
W = subset(CAR, subset=Age>=16 & Age<=17, select=c("Name","END","MEZ","EKT","X","Y"))
```